# Debian has wrong source.list file after update

Tags: debian, apt, mysql

I have just carried out an upgrade from `debian 11` to `debian 12`, and that appears to be fine. I now need to update the mysql instance to 8.0.34.

I have downloaded the latest `mysql-apt-config` and installed it, but when I look at the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list` it seems to think I have ubuntu? The process I have followed is:

```
cd /root
wget https://repo.mysql.com/mysql-apt-config_0.8.26-1_all.deb
dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.26-1_all.deb
```

Before the update to `mysql-apt-config` the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list` has lines like:

```
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ buster mysql-apt-config
```

but after it has:

```
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/mysql-apt-config.gpg] http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ lunar mysql-apt-config
```

I have manually changed it to:

```
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ bullseye mysql-apt-config
```

and it seems to work fine.

I'm just wondering if anyone can explain why it thinks it is Ubuntu, and where this information comes from so I can fix it for the future.

Comment: that's odd, the `.deb` package you installed just writes about 4 files to `/usr/share/doc/.....` also ... if you've upgraded from Debian 11 to 12, why was your mysql.list using `buster` (Debian 10) and why have you manually changed it to use `bullseye` (Debian 11) - edit: ahh, nevermind ... mysql hasn't released a bookworm version

Comment: I believe the server was probably upgraded from debian 10 previously, whreas MySQL hasn't been touched in some time, hence the reason it still showed Buster in the file.